# Comparing .txt files in Python using askdirectory

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the below code to run through a directory and select all of the files and compare them to an inserted wordlist file. However I get the following error `TypeError: invalid file: ['C:/Users/Nathan/Desktop/chats\\(1,).out']` I cannot figure out how to change the os.path.join to correctly show the file location.

```
    self.wordopp = askdirectory(title="Select chat log directory")
    path = self.wordopp
    files = os.listdir(path)
    paths = []
    wordlist = self.wordop
    for file in files:
        paths.append(os.path.join(path, file))
        f = open(wordlist)
        l = set(w.strip().lower() for w in f)
        with open(paths) as f:
            found = False
            file = open("out.txt", "w")
            for line in paths:
                line = line.lower()
                if any(w in line for w in l):
                    found = True
                    file.write(line)
                    print(line)
                    if not found:
                        print(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this line of code:

```
with open(paths) as f:
```

Ask yourself, "what is `paths`"? It is a *list* of filenames, not a single file. That's pretty much what the error is telling you: that a list is an invalid file.

Considering that you are looping over a list of filenames, my guess is that your intention is to do:

```
with open(file) as f:
```

or maybe

```
with open(paths[-1]) as f:
```